# Yii URL Rewrite not working

Tags: yii

I am developing a Yii app using YiiBoilerPlate.

I am able to get to `http://localhost/testapp/frontend/www/`

when I click on login its giving me the message

*The requested URL /testapp/frontend/www/site/login/ was not found on this server.*

is there any config missing?

**.htaccess has:**

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule . index.php
```

**frontend/config/main.php has:**

```
        'urlManager' => array(
            'urlFormat' => 'path',
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'urlSuffix' => '/',
            'rules' => $params['url.rules']
        ),
```

**in the apache access logs..it has:**

```
*127.0.0.1 - - [23/Apr/2013:18:04:24 -0500] "GET /testapp/frontend/www/site/login/ HTTP/1.1" 404 516 "http://localhost/testapp/frontend/www/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux i686; rv:20.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/20.0"*
```

Tried all relevent suggestions online and still didn't work. any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Seems you have `loginRequire` on the `http://localhost/testapp/frontend/www/` and it redirect you to `loginUrl` which does not exists.

You can easily solve it by adding to config:

```
// ......
'components'=>array(
   'user'=>array(
       'loginUrl'=>array('user/login'), # path to login controller/action
   ),
),
```

Otherwise if you don't have login controller, error will raise with message:

```
The requested URL /testapp/frontend/www/user/login/ was not found on this server.
```

Comment: do I need this if I am using the the login action in SiteController? default loginUrl is '/site/login', right? One more thing, I noticed is /site/index is also giving the same error

Comment: @skris `user/login` just an example, you should write `site/login`. You also should post your route rules which are in the `$params['url.rules']`, other way I can't help you.

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work. Here is the URL rules. Here is the url rules.`'url.rules' => array(
    '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',
    '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
    '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',`

Comment: I noticed that it shows `href="/testapp/frontend/www/site/login/">` in view source.... shouldn't it be just `'site/login'`. would that be the problem? menu is                                    `array('label'=>'<img src="'.Yii::app()->request->baseUrl.'/images/Little-Login.png" alt="Site Login"/>', 'url'=>array('/site/login'),'linkOptions'=>array('class'=>'tooltips2'), 'visible' => Yii::app()->user->isGuest),`

Comment: In your last comment, try to replace `url'=>array('/site/login')` to `url'=>array('site/login')` - remove the slash.

Comment: The same with the first comment.

Comment: its still giving me the same error. I deleted the previously created testapp and unzipped yiiboilerplate again to testapp and still getting the same error.  same thing with site/index and others links.  I have `'user'=>array(
           'loginUrl'=>array('site/login'), # path to login controller/action
      ),`  frontend/config/main  not sure what is happening.